# What is an alternative to curl | bash to execute scripts for upgrades in Dockerfiles?

Tags: bash, dockerfile

I would like to know what are the alternatives to using `curl ... | bash ...` to upgrade a package to a given version in a Dockerfile. It has been found that someone placed a [backdoor in Codecov Bash Uploader](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2021/04/backdoor-found-in-codecov-bash-uploader.html), which would allow an attacker to export info from a target's CI environment. I am on RHEL 8 and for the moment, my Dockerfile uses something like:

```
RUN curl -sL <script-url> | bash -  && \
  yum remove -y <package> && \
  yum install -y <package> && \
  ...
```

Comment: `<package-url> | bash -` why would you stream a package to bash? That should give you a lot of errors. You can stream _a script_ to bash. The _way_ to install anything, is to download the package, with md5 sum, check it, then download public key of the developer, check if package is properly signed, then install it.

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk, you were right, I edited the question.